# How to transfer Set-Cookie headers in Angular SSR Universal app?

Tags: angular, cookies, angular-universal, angular-httpclient

Backend API returns HTTP response with some set-cookie headers.
Angular Universal calls this API using HttpClient, but the set-cookie headers are not present in the response.

The below code fragment returns null.

```
console.log((<HttpResponse<any>>response).headers.getAll('set-cookie'))
```

I want the set-cookie headers to be copied to the response returned by the express server.

My idea was to just copy set-cookie headers from backend response into express response but it seems Angular filters out set-cookie headers. How to prevent that?